# What is seen in the code if the user answers No to new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, filesystemobject

I don't know what to test in the code if the user answers No to new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). Any info?

Answer (score 0):

If user answers no to new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"), the console will show the error: `Automation server can't create object`.

Set the Internet options of IE: Tools ->Internet options ->Security ->Custom level ->ActiveX controls and plug-ins ->Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting: **Disable**.

Then I test with below code in IE and use F12 to check the console:

```
 <script>
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var f1 = fso.createtextfile("c:\myjstest.txt", true);   
 </script>
```